# Like box - custom height issue

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, facebook-likebox

From several days I have some problems with Facebook Like box, I want to set custom height e.g. 800px, but if I switch off "Show faces" it has it's default height, if I switch on "Show faces" i has my custom height, but still there is default height feed and a lot of rows with faces...

Any help ?

EDIT:

Just to be clear, my code was working more than half year without any changes, it just happen couple days ago,

Comment: Please Post your code here.

Comment: My code doesn't change from a half of year (or even more) because it was working OK, but will try to post it asap

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution:

**Replace with your info:** (*i set the height to **800px***)

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/username-of-youe-page" data-width="292" data-height="800" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>
```

**And this is your JavaScript:** *(preferably to be added immediately after the **"body"** tag*)

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**Succes!**

Comment: did you read carefully my post, and subposts ? My code was working for more than half a year, but unfortunetlly couple days ago something has happened and it is not working now.... (please check if you can set custom height without breaking plugin on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ )

Comment: Yes @kuba i readed your post. What have I said to you, is tested. Please try and make a screenshot with result.

Comment: Sorry David, no JS :-) only iframe solution, but if I use official FB generator It seems that there is some bug there ( http://i49.tinypic.com/k0hr0m.png ), maybe I will just report official bug to FB...

Comment: Ok then. Keep me informed.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/481135598603996?browse=search_50dc0fab3fe838400112652 it is now official bug, still no t working ok :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is a Facebook bug itself and is still not fixed. I've filed a bug report to them and will update my post accordingly when it gets resolved.

Comment: Could you share some information on this bug? Is it documented?

Comment: They replied that there's no way to increase the height of the stream box and that is there to stay by their design. So we're pretty much stuck now. There's basically nothing to do. No CSS nor Javascript can touch the contents of the iframe.